# JavaScript variable reference in DOM Script not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, vite

I am new to Vite and want just one simple thing -> to reference a variable in my DOM that I declared in the main.js.

important code from main.js:

```
let getThis = 'Why does this not work';
```

important code from index.html:

```
<body>
<p id="test">not working</p>
<script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
<script type="module">
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = getThis;
</script>
```

Exmple: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-urotp2?file=main.js,index.html,counter.js&terminal=dev I searched the Internet for 2 Days now:/

First I had a problem using Bootstrap in combination with Vite. I wanted to trigger a Modal via Javascript like in this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-4akyeo?file=src%2Fjs%2Fmain.js,src%2Findex.html

important code from index.html:

```
<script>
    const myModalAlternative = new bootstrap.Modal('#exampleModal');
    myModalAlternative.show();
  </script>
```

important code from main.js:

```
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
window.bootstrap = bootstrap;
```

But I always received `Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined`(look in the console ). I researched and found out that this is because the bootstrap variable is not linked to the window object but this didn´t fix the issue. So I broke it down and realized this is a more general problem. I assume that it has something to do with the bundling of the files and now the variables aren't readable in the <script>.

Is this even possible or am I missing something here? Is this maybe a normal JavaScript scope issue? Thankful for any help.

Comment: Please post your code directly in your post, rather than as a link.

Comment: @mykaf Thanks for the advise. I've done it and will keep doing it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Arnaud from Vite I have solved the problem.
Here is What he told me:

> Variables in ESM modules are scoped to the modules, you can only
> access them in other modules by exporting them and using import in the
> other module, like you did for the counter. More information here:
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules
>
> If you want to bypass this, you can always set something on window
> object to make it global, but that should be used only exceptionally

So I researched JS Modules and fixed both problems mentioned above.

#### Solving the main problem mentioned in the title

I had to export the variable from a file which is imported to my main.js and then import the variable in my .

code from custom.js:

```
export let getThis = 'Why does this not work';
```

important code from index.html:

```
import { getThis } from './custom.js';
```

see [main problem solved](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-h6cps7?file=main.js,index.html,counter.js,custom.js&terminal=dev)

#### Fixing 'Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined'

I just had to add `type="module"` to `<script>` and `bootstrap.Modal('#exampleModal');` is working now.
Keep in mind this works only if you first made bootstrap global like:

```
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
window.bootstrap = bootstrap; // <- add to window object to bypass the scope and make it global
```

see [bootstrap problem solved - Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-4akyeo-zphkv1?file=src%2Fjs%2Fmain.js,src%2Findex.html)

I hope this helped someone.